# How can I resize a ckEditor instance from inside an AngularJS directive?

Tags: angularjs, ckeditor

I have the following code:

```
app.directive('ckEditor', [function () {
    return {
        require: '?ngModel',
        link: function ($scope, elm, attr, ngModel) {

            var ck = null;
            var config = attr.ckSize;

            ck = CKEDITOR.replace(elm[0]);
            if (config == 'narrow') {
                ck.resize(700, 357);
            } else {
                ck.resize(900, 357);
            }
```

I am trying to resize the ckEditor instance but it gives me an error message saying:

```
TypeError: Cannot call method 'setSize' of undefined
    at CKEDITOR.editor.resize (http://127.0.0.1:81/Scripts/ckeditor/ckeditor.js:294:23)
```

Can someone give me advice as to how I can change the instance of that editor's size ?

Comment: the question does not make sense to me. did you try elementary debugging?

Comment: First post the code of ckeditor on line 294 character:23 to understand what object is undefined

Comment: Hard to post as that line is about 1000 characters long :-(  It seems to be here: (m.style.width="1%")

Answer (score 1):

This is a create instance code from [here](http://rev.ckeditor.com/ckeditor/trunk/6593/_samples/ajax.html) :

```
function createEditor()
{
    if ( editor )
        return;

    var html = document.getElementById( 'editorcontents' ).innerHTML;

    // Create a new editor inside the <div id="editor">, setting its value to html
    var config = {};
    editor = CKEDITOR.appendTo( 'editor', config, html );
}
```

Make sure a div with id='editorcontents' exists in your code:

```
<div id='editorcontents'></div>
```

At the bottom of the [help page](http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/api/CKEDITOR.config-cfg-resize_enabled) there is `width` attribute did you try :

```
ck.width = 700;
ck.height = 357;
```

Comment: I suspect the `ck` variable is `null`, that is why the thing throws up. :)

Comment: I think not. Later in the directive I issue a bunch of ck.on statements and they work fine.

Comment: Mehdi - The ckEditor is getting created inside an AngularJS directive. I'll post some more code. Thanks